# Why does my Eclipse Galileo not have Windows->Preferences->Server page?

Tags: eclipse, preferences, galileo

I downloaded Eclipse Galileo (3.5.1) SR1 and Eclipse SDK 3.5.1 and neither of them have a "Server" page on the Windows->Preferences screen.

Any ideas why?

Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse SDK 3.5.1 "[classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/classic.php)" does not include [WST (Web Tools)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php)
Even the [RCP edition](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/rcp.php) only include it partially

> WST: This subproject will provide support for integrating Web servers into Eclipse as first-class execution environments for Web applications.
>   This support will include the ability to configure Web servers and associate them with Web projects

[alt text http://www.noocodecommit.com/blog/nicogiard/images/05_01_2008-18_01_55.png](http://www.noocodecommit.com/blog/nicogiard/images/05_01_2008-18_01_55.png)

See **[Eclipse Compare Packages page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)**